# Prove that a function of two variables does not satisfy the conditions of the Differentiability Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{2} y \log(x^2+y^2), & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
> 0, & (x,y) = (0,0)
> \end{cases}$
>
> You may assume that this is a continuous function.  Prove that $f$ does not satisfy the conditions of the "Differentiability Theorem" above at the point $(0,0)$.

**Differentiability Theorem.** $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at a point $x=a$ if each of the entries of the matrix $D f(a)$ exists at $a$ and is continuous at $a$; in other words, all of the partial derivatives which make up $D f(a)$ exist and are continuous functions at $a$.

I have tried using the limit definitions to find the partial derivatives.  I get for $x$ that it is $0$, but for $y$ I find that the limit includes the log function which causes the limit to go to negative infinity.  I believe I need to prove that the tangent plane from the linear approximation is not actually tangent, but I can't get the equation for the plane.

Comment: Note: $\:$ That Differentiability Theorem is only true if one's definition of continuity requires that $\hspace{1.03 in}$ the function be defined in a neighborhood of the relevant point. $\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}y \log(y^2)}{y} = \frac{1}{2} \log(y^2)$. We have $\lim_{y \to  0} \frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y} = -\infty$, hence the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$ does not exist at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Hence $\frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial y} = [Df((0,0))]_2$ does not exist.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the subscript 2 in the last statement is for??I am a bit confused.Sorry if its something obvious that I missed.Does it mean the second partial derivative(w.r.t. y)??

Comment: The 'Differentiability theorem' mentioned above requires that all entries of $Df(a)$ exist. The 2 subscript refers to the second entry of $Df((0,0))$. I added a little to the answer to clarify.

Comment: Ah thanks. Thats what I wanted.